# How do I add a do-while loop in this program so that if the input is less than 4 it doesn't print anything

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int row, i, j;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);

        for (i=1; i<=row; i++) {

        for (j=1; j<=row; j++) {

            if (i==1 || i==row || i+j==row+1) {

                printf("*");
            }
            else 
            {
            printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program prints out the letter "Z" out of stars.
I have to add a do-while loop in this. (This is for school, you can clearly see that I'm a begginer.)

Comment: for starters you have a bracket mismatch, this code won't compile.

Comment: Please show a properly formatted example if input and expected output. Once with an input >= 4 and once with an input < 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
do {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    if (row < 4) puts("Try again");
} while (row < 4);
```